# SQL nested query with join operations

Tags: sql

I have a table P with person1id and person2id columns, and a table J with each person's personId and their name columns. I want to have a query that generates a table of person1id, person2id, name1, name2 columns. In the result, name1 is the name of person1id, name2 is the name of person2id.  Is it possible to do this via nested query?

The tables look like below

table P

| person1id | person2id |
| --- | --- |
| p1_1 | p2_1 |
| p1_2 | p2_2 |

table J

| personId | name |
| --- | --- |
| p1_1 | name1 |
| p1_2 | name2 |
| p2_1 | name3 |
| p2_2 | name4 |

The expected result looks like

| person1id | person2id | name1 | name2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1_1 | p2_1 | name1 | name3 |
| p1_2 | p2_2 | name2 | name4 |

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: @D-Shih presto sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a query without join.

```sql
SELECT person1id,   
       person2id,
       (SELECT name FROM J WHERE personId = person1id) AS name1,
       (SELECT name FROM J WHERE personId = person2id) AS name2
FROM P
```

Another one with left join.

```sql
SELECT person1id,   
       person2id,
       j1.name as name1,
       j2.name as name2
FROM P
LEFT JOIN J j1 ON person1id = j1.personId
LEFT JOIN J j2 ON person2id = j2.personId
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `join` with condition aggregate function, the `CASE WHEN` condition depends on your new column logic which is your expectation.

**Query #1**

```
SELECT person1id,   
       person2id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN personId IN ('p1_1','p1_2') THEN name END) name1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN personId IN ('p2_1','p2_2') THEN name END) name2
FROM P
INNER JOIN J ON personId IN (P.person1id,P.person2id)
GROUP BY person1id, 
       person2id;
```

| person1id | person2id | name1 | name2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1_1 | p2_1 | name1 | name3 |
| p1_2 | p2_2 | name2 | name4 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8xudwRyb9giisQ99UDrD3n/0)

Comment: Thanks!. I added some clarification - "In the result, name1 is the name of person1id, name2 is the name of person2id.". Is it possible to achieve that without hardcoding the person ids?

Comment: I added an answer that seems to work.